# How to connect Cisco Catalyst 2960G using a RJ45 Console Port

Tags: cisco, cisco-catalyst, cable, linux

Got a used [Cisco Catalyst 2960G-24TC-L](http://ttps://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/switches/catalyst-2960g-24tc-l-switch/model.html) switch for studying networking and having a fundamental issue. As I new to networking, I'm trying to figure out what type of cable I need to use for connecting between the switch and my laptop.

The switch has an RJ45 type for a console port and I plugged a CAT5 cable into it and on the other end, I have a RJ45 to USB. Connected the USB end to my laptop. I'm running a CentOS 7 and tried

```
demsg /dev | grep tty
```

and I get a ttyS0 as the output. Further, I tried,

```
screen /dev/ttyS0 9600
```

I get a blank screen with a flashing cursor. Nothing happens when I hit enter.

Any idea what might be going on here? Should I be going with RJ45 console to DB9 and then DB9 to USB?

Comment: (0) *RJ45 to USB* serial adapter??? (1) linux usb serial is /dev/ttyUSB# (2) the 2960's have a usb console as well that linux should detect -- I've never tried.

Comment: Recent 2960X series  may have an USB console, but a venerable 2960G-24-TC-L? That'd be somewhat of a surprise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The console port on Cisco devices might have RJ45 (8p8c) form factor, but it is not Ethernet, but RS-232 serial.

Usually, the Cisco device comes with a RJ45(serial)-to-DB9 console cable (light blue, flat ribbon cable, not twisted pair), and you would use an USB-to-DB9 RS232 converter at the computer end, as DB9 serial ports have become rare on computers.

USB-to-RJ45(serial) adapters (in the form of a 1.5-2m cable) have also become available, eliminating the DB9 interface (re)conversion altogether.

The RJ45 section of such cabling *may* be extended using a straight Cat5/Cat6 patch cables.

Some recent Cisco models have an USB-to-Serial converter built-in, and they offer a mini-USB-5pin port, to which you can connect a computer directly.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use **RJ45 to USB** for Console port (Because there isn't a convertor!). You should buy a [**USB to RJ45 Rollover Console Cable**](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00GN5OHIW) to connect to Cisco Console line.

Also, I tested it. You can buy and put **[RS232 Serial Cable](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01N5QK3OZ)** to [**RS-232 Serial to USB**](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0007T27H8) and connected to cisco consoe line.

Comment: Thank you. I have ordered a RJ45 to DB9 (RD232) and DB9 (RS232) to USB.